# Is it possible to retrieve the entire list of named AnnotationSets in GATE?

Tags: java, nlp, gate

is it possible to retrieve the entire list of an Annotation Set in GATE? This line of code returns all the items of a GATE document that belong to the AnnotationSet called "EMail";

```
AnnotationSet annSet = doc.getAnnotations().get("EMail");
```

Now, how can I know all of the Annotations' Set names instead of the only "EMail"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this the answer to your question:

```
AnnotationSet annSet = doc.getAnnotations();
```

---

I think you mix two different terms: *annotation set* and *annotation type*. Be careful about these two...

There are several methods of `gate.Document` and `gate.AnnotationSet` that can be used:

- `gate.Document.getAnnotations()` 
  ... all annotations from the default (without name) annotation set.
- `gate.Document.getAnnotations(String setName)`
  ... all annotations from named annotation set with name `setName`.
- `gate.AnnotationSet.get(String anntoationType)`
  ... select only annotations with given `anntoationType`.
- `gate.Document.getAnnotationSetNames()`
  ... get all the names of named annotation sets in a document
- `gate.AnnotationSet.getAllTypes()`
  ... get set of all annotation type names of annotations present in given annotation set.

See more details in javadoc:

- [SimpleAnnotationSet](https://jenkins.gate.ac.uk/job/gate-core/javadoc/gate/SimpleAnnotationSet.html)
- [SimpleDocument](https://jenkins.gate.ac.uk/job/gate-core/javadoc/gate/SimpleDocument.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc;
// create/manipulate the document...

Set<String> names = doc.getAnnotationSetNames();
Map<String, AnnotationSet> namedAnnSets = doc.getNamedAnnotationSets();

// The default AS always exists
AnnotationSet defaultAS = doc.getAnnotations();
```

Note that a GATE document always has a default (unnamed) annotation set, which is not included in the set of names or map of named sets.